# Show table data based on ID in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

I have a table that store the data of ID, ID Login, Name, etc. But i just want to show the data based on ID Login

Here My Controller :

```
function index(){
    $data['hasil'] = $this->M_user_lapor->index_model();
    $this->load->view('v_user_lapor/index', $data);
}
```

My Model :

```
function index_model(){
    $baca = $this->db->query('select * from user_lapor');
    if($baca->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($baca->result() as $data){
            $hasil[] = array(
                'id_login'=>$data->id_login,
                'id_lapor'=>$data->id_lapor,
                'nm_unit'=>$data->nm_unit,
                'pic_1'=>$data->pic_1,
                'pic_2'=>$data->pic_2,
                'ip_wan'=>$data->ip_wan,
                'ip_lan'=>$data->ip_lan,
                'prov'=>$data->prov,
                'icn_sid'=>$data->icn_sid,
                'tlkm_sid'=>$data->tlkm_sid,
                'status'=>$data->status,

            );
        }
        return json_encode ($hasil);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

View :

```
 <tbody>
    <?php
       if ($hasil){
         $no = 1;
         $array = json_decode($hasil, true);
         foreach($array as $data) {
         ?>
       <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><?php echo $no++;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['nm_unit'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['pic_1'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['pic_2'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['ip_wan'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['ip_lan'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['prov'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['icn_sid'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data['tlkm_sid'];?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php
          }
           }
       ?>
     </tbody>
```

As you can see, there is id_login inside my model, and i want to show the table data based on it, hopefully somebody can help me because i'm just using the codeigniter, thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by myself, lol. I just pass the id_login value from session, so i add this to my controller :

```
function index(){
    $id_login = $this->session->id_login;
    $data['hasil'] = $this->M_user_lapor->index_model($id_login);
    $this->load->view('v_user_lapor/index', $data);
}
```

And call it to my model :

```
function index_model($id_login){
    $baca = $this->db->query('select * from user_lapor where id_login='.$id_login);
    if($baca->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($baca->result() as $data){
            $hasil[] = array(
                'id_login'=>$data->id_login,
                'id_lapor'=>$data->id_lapor,
                'nm_unit'=>$data->nm_unit,
                'pic_1'=>$data->pic_1,
                'pic_2'=>$data->pic_2,
                'ip_wan'=>$data->ip_wan,
                'ip_lan'=>$data->ip_lan,
                'prov'=>$data->prov,
                'icn_sid'=>$data->icn_sid,
                'tlkm_sid'=>$data->tlkm_sid,
                'status'=>$data->status,
            );
        }
        return json_encode ($hasil);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```